Is omitting apostrophe after "husband" in "the husband of your husband or wife’s sister" correct?
I saw one entry in the definition of "brother-in-law" from Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English Dictionary written as follows:

the husband of your husband or wife’s sister.

But I'm not sure this is a typo in the dictionary or it's correct to omit the apostrophe after "husband". Should it be written as follows:

the husband of your husband's or wife’s sister?


Your version is certainly more clear and unambiguous. In a context that called for rigorous correction, it would be preferable. And one could certainly argue that dictionary definitions constitute one such context. So I would say congratulations, your intuition is sound here. (And by sound I mean valid, reliable. I don’t mean the vibrations in air that are perceived with one’s ears.)

I would prefer "The husband of a spouse's sister", so that the alternative isn't even needed.
